# .NET 8 SDK not installing correctly on Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu, sdk

I've installed the .NET 8 SDK following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install
Running these commands:

```
wget https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh -O dotnet-install.sh
chmod +x ./dotnet-install.sh
./dotnet-install.sh --version latest
```

It says it installs successfully, but when I run dotnet --info, it only lists .NET 6 and 7. .NET 8 seems to install successfully to /home/usr/.dotnet/sdk, but the system doesn't seem to recognize that it's there. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I follow the official steps to install manually.
[image]
Copy the direct link.
[image]
Download SDK from direct link. `Wget <Direct link>`
Then run the manual steps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#example
[image]
To make he environment variable take effect permanently ,I add following to `vim /etc/profile/`

```
DOTNET_ROOT=/home/jerry/test3/.dotnet
export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools
```

Then run `source /etc/profile` to refresh configuration.